# How to Open .xll file in 64 bit Windows 2010 and Office 2016

Tags: excel, vba

Earlier I could able to open .xll in 32 bit Office 2013. After system upgrade I could not open .xll file in 64 bit Office 2016. When I try to open the file it open in Junk character. I have alreay added Add-ins of .xll. Also tried to the open the file from

`"C:\Users\[userId]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART"`

still no luck. Suggestion on this will be great help.

Comment: As far as I remember, .xll files are COM add-ins usually written in C++. I doubt you could have opened them with any version of Excel for editing. Maybe you mean .xla or .xlam files, those are VBA add-ins.

Comment: May be that .xll file created from c++ but we want to open it in excel vba editor. Anymore help appreciated...Thanks in advance.